# Department names(with employee name) with more than 2 employee and salary greater than 90% of respective department average salary

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to generate a SQL query to find the Department names(with employee name) with more than 2 employee **whose** salary greater than 90% of respective department average salary. My  SQL Code is working fine , it has no Syntax errors but the output is giving me additional data. The table is as follos

```
JONES         ACCOUNTING    3000
STEEL         ACCOUNTING    2500
WILSON        RESEARCH      3000
WOLFE         RESEARCH      2500
LEE           RESEARCH      2400
LANCASTER     SALES         2000
JACKSON       SALES         2500
FISHER        SALES         3000
ADAMS         IT            2000
MILLER        IT            1000
SCOTT         IT            2500
SMITH         IT            2900
KING          EXECUTIVE     5000
JOST          EXECUTIVE     4500
CLARK         EXECUTIVE     4000
```

My code is as follows.

```
Select department_name , employee_name 
from department d , employee e 
where e.department_id = d.department_id
and (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Employee E 
     WHERE E.department_ID = D.department_ID) > 2    
    and salary > 
    0.9*(SELECT ROUND(AVG(salary),2)
    FROM employee e_inner
    WHERE e_inner.department_id = e.department_id);
```

I notice that my code returns the value of department with more than 2 employees **and** salary > 90% of department's average salary. whereas I am looking for departments with more than 2 employees **whose** salary is more than 90% of department avg salary

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Do you need an alias other than E to differ from e?

Comment: Its not case sensitive. My output should give me only 2 departments , its giving me 4 at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
select *
from (
  select department_name, 
         employee_name,
         sum(case when salary > avg_dept_sal * 0.9 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by department_id) as greater_count
  from (
     select d.department_name,
            e.department_id,
            e.employee_name,
            e.salary,
            count(*) over (partition by e.department_id) as dept_count,
            avg(salary) over (partition by e.department_id) as avg_dept_sal
     from employee e
       join department d on e.department_id = d.department_id
  ) t1
) t2
where greater_count  >= 2
```

This will return all employees of those departments. If you only want to see those employees whose salary is actually greater than the 90% you need to add another condition to the outer where clause to only select those.

Comment: @Gary1266: see my edit. Btw if this is homework then please tell us so.

Comment: It is a practise excercise given at the end of every chapter in a standard txtbook, but since I have just started  writing SQL code , I am struggling a bit. The Output of this Question is as follows IT <ADAMS, SCOTT, SMITH>
RESEARCH <LEE, WILSON, WOLFE>
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The below stated query will give result as desired without using any analytics. Simple & Easy just like English.

**

- *
- with T as  (select empname, deptno, salary from employee e1 where
  salary > (select avg(salary)*0.9 from employee e2 where
  e2.deptno=e1.deptno group by deptno having count(empname)>2)) select 
  T.empname, deptname, salary from T, department where
  T.deptno=department.deptno;

*

**

I executed this query successfully on Oracle database.